# JS table value update onchange

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I would like to update the values in a table immediately below a form that i have. Quantities in the cart are increased and decreased and the value in the table below is to match.At the moment the increase/decrease works for the input field for the form but I cant get any change on the table field.

JS for Form field-

```
/* Input incrementer*/
$(".numbers-row").append('<div class="inc button_inc">+</div><div class="dec button_inc">-</div>');
$(".button_inc").on("click", function () {

    var $button = $(this);
    var oldValue = $button.parent().find("input").val();

    if ($button.text() == "+") {
        var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) + 1;
    } else {
        // Don't allow decrementing below zero
        if (oldValue > 1) {
            var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) - 1;
        } else {
            newVal = 0;
        }
    }
    $button.parent().find("input").val(newVal);
});
});
```

HTML -

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Adults</label>
                    <div class="numbers-row">
                        <input type="text" value="1" id="adult" onchange="myFunction()" class="qty2 form-control" name="quantity">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Children</label>
                    <div class="numbers-row">
                        <input type="text" value="0" id="child" class="qty2 form-control" name="quantity">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <table class="table table_summary">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Adults
            </td>
            <script>
                function myFunction() {
                    var x = document.getElementById("adult").value;
                    document.getElementById("adultvalue").innerHTML = "&pound;" + x;
                }
            </script>
            <td class="text-right">
                <p id="adultvalue">2</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Children
            </td>
            <td class="text-right">
                0
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Total amount
            </td>
            <td class="text-right">
                3x £52
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="total">
            <td>
                Total cost
            </td>
            <td class="text-right">
                £154
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check below snippet. I have tried to cover all your solutions. For child I have set 26 pounds and for adult 52 pound in the demo. You can change it as per your need. If you found any query please let me know.

```js
$(".numbers-row").append('<div class="inc button_inc">+</div><div class="dec button_inc">-</div>');

//Here for example took £52 for adult and £26 for child. you can change as per your need.
$(".button_inc").on("click", function () {
    var $button = $(this);
    var oldValue = $button.parent().find("input").val();
 if(oldValue==''){oldValue = 0;}
    if ($button.text() == "+") {
        var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) + 1;
    } else {
        // Don't allow decrementing below zero
        if (oldValue > 1) {
            var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) - 1;
        } else {
            newVal = 0;
        }
    }
    $button.parent().find("input").val(newVal);
    //This line under
    $('#adultvalue').html('&pound;' + newVal);
 updatePerson();
});
function updatePerson() { 
 var adultQuant = $("#adult").val();
 if(adultQuant==""){adultQuant=0;}
 var childQuant = $("#child").val();
 if(childQuant==""){childQuant=0;}
 
 $("#adultvalue").html(adultQuant);
 $("#childvalue").html(childQuant);
 $("#adultcalc").html(adultQuant);
 $("#childcalc").html(childQuant);
 var totalCost = (adultQuant*52) + (childQuant*26);
 $("#totalcost").html(totalCost);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
  <div class="form-group">
   <label>Adults</label>
   <div class="numbers-row">
    <input type="text" id="adult" onchange="updatePerson()" class="qty2 form-control" name="quantity">
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
  <div class="form-group">
   <label>Children</label>
   <div class="numbers-row">
    <input type="text" id="child" onchange="updatePerson()" class="qty2 form-control" name="quantity">
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<br>
<table class="table table_summary">
 <tbody>
 <tr>
  <td>
   Adults
  </td>
  <td class="text-right">
   <p id="adultvalue">0</p>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   Children
  </td>
  <td class="text-right">
   <p id="childvalue">0</p>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   Total amount
  </td>
  <td class="text-right">
   <p>Adults : <span id="adultcalc">0</span> x £52</p>
   <p>Child : <span id="childcalc">0</span> x £26</p>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="total">
  <td>
   Total cost
  </td>
  <td class="text-right">
   £<p id="totalcost">0</p>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

onchange is triggered when the control is blurred. So that will not work.

You can add this to you jquery :

```
$(".numbers-row").append('<div class="inc button_inc">+</div><div class="dec button_inc">-</div>');
$(".button_inc").on("click", function () {

    var $button = $(this);
    var oldValue = $button.parent().find("input").val();

    if ($button.text() == "+") {
        var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) + 1;
    } else {
        // Don't allow decrementing below zero
        if (oldValue > 1) {
            var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) - 1;
        } else {
            newVal = 0;
        }
    }
    $button.parent().find("input").val(newVal);
    //This line under
    $('#adultvalue').html('&pound;' + newVal);
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I rearranged some sections and now the result is:

```js
$(function () {
  $(".numbers-row").append('<div class="inc button_inc">+</div><div class="dec button_inc">-</div>');
  $(".button_inc").on("click", function () {
    var $button = $(this);
    var oldValue = $button.parent().find("input").val();
    if ($button.text() == "+") {
      var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) + 1;
    } else {
      // Don't allow decrementing below zero
      if (oldValue > 1) {
        var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) - 1;
      } else {
        newVal = 0;
      }
    }
    $button.parent().find("input").val(newVal).trigger('input');
  });

  $('#adult, #child').on('input', function(e) {
    if (this.id == 'adult') {
      $('#adultvalue').text($(this).val());
    } else {
      $('#childrenvalue').text($(this).val());
    }
    $('#totalammountvalue').text(+$('#adult').val() + +$('#child').val());
    $('#totalcostvalue').text((+$('#adult').val() + +$('#child').val()) * 52);
  });

  $('#adult').trigger('input');
});
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Adults</label>

            <div class="numbers-row">
                <input type="text" value="1" id="adult" onchange="myFunction()" class="qty2 form-control"
                       name="quantity">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Children</label>

            <div class="numbers-row">
                <input type="text" value="0" id="child" class="qty2 form-control" name="quantity">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<table class="table table_summary">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Adults
        </td>
        <script>
            function myFunction() {
                var x = document.getElementById("adult").value;
                document.getElementById("adultvalue").innerHTML = "&pound;" + x;
            }
        </script>
        <td class="text-right">
            <p id="adultvalue">2</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Children
        </td>
        <td class="text-right">
            <p id="childrenvalue">0</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Total amount
        </td>
        <td class="text-right">
            <span id="totalammountvalue">0</span>x £52
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="total">
        <td>
            Total cost
        </td>
        <td class="text-right">
            £<span id="totalcostvalue">0</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a couple of things to your HTML markup to get it working and wrapped everything in a function in order to add the events correctly.

HTML

```
   <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group adults">
                <label>Adults</label>
                <div class="numbers-row">
                    <input type="text" value="1" id="adult" onchange="myFunction()" class="qty2 form-control" name="quantity">
                   <div class="inc button_inc">+</div><div class="dec button_inc">-</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group children">
                <label>Children</label>
                <div class="numbers-row">
                    <input type="text" value="0" id="child" class="qty2 form-control" name="quantity">
                    <div class="inc button_inc">+</div><div class="dec button_inc">-</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <table class="table table_summary">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Adults
        </td>
        <script>
            function myFunction() {
                var x = document.getElementById("adult").value;
                document.getElementById("adultvalue").innerHTML = "&pound;" + x;
            }
        </script>
        <td class="text-right">
            <p id="adultvalue">1</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Children
        </td>
        <td class="text-right">
            <p id="childrenvalue">
            0
            </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Total amount
        </td>
        <td class="text-right">
            3x £52
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="total">
        <td>
            Total cost
        </td>
        <td class="text-right">
            £154
        </td>
    </tr>
```

JS

```
function addIncrementDecrementHandlers(formContainerSelector, cellToUpdateSelector) {
  $(formContainerSelector + ' .button_inc').on("click", function () {

      var $button = $(this);
      var oldValue = $button.parent().find("input").val();

      if ($button.text() == "+") {
          var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) + 1;
      } else {
          // Don't allow decrementing below zero
          if (oldValue > 1) {
              var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) - 1;
          } else {
              newVal = 0;
          }
      }
      $button.parent().find("input").val(newVal);
      //Here you set the new value in the table cell
        $(cellToUpdateSelector).html(newVal);
  });
}

addIncrementDecrementHandlers('.adults', '#adultvalue');
addIncrementDecrementHandlers('.children', '#childrenvalue');
```

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/paf1soub/) is the jsfiddle so you see it working.